# Store a bunch of inputs on page into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of inputs on a page, ie:

```
<input name="user[name]" />
<input name="user[phone]" />
<input name="user[email]" />
```

And what I'd like to do, is on submitting the form is grab all those variables of the user array and store them in a javascript array.

Ie, I would think something like this would work:

```
$('submit').click(function(e){

 e.preventDefault;


 $.each($('input[name=user*') as var) {

     var user[] = this.input value etc;

  }

});
```

But thats because I don't know much about javascript arrays.

How is this sort of thing achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
$('submit').click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   var user = [];

   $('input[name*=user]').each(function(index) {
      user[index] = $(this).val();
   });
}
```

Comment: 1. `preventDefault` is a method - you need to call it with `()`; 2. Use `[]` to create an empty array - it's better

Comment: Copied preventDefault from the original code :)  Fixed now..  Thanks for the hint about empty brackets.

Answer (score 3):

use the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function

```
$('input').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

[image]

Comment: The OP needs an array of input values, not input names

Comment: `this.value` to retrieve the value - no need for jQuery here.

Comment: This solution seems very good and elegant but how do I then use those variable in the array? are these values now mapped to an array or do I still need to do something like var array_name = ??

Comment: `get(0)` to get the first var in the array. `get(1)` to get the second as so on. Check example http://jsfiddle.net/UrCVS/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you give all of your element's the class `my_inputs` or something, and then get them with `$(".my_inputs")`. That way, you now have an object of those inputs and can loop through them like this:

```
var inputs = $(".my_inputs");
inputs.each(function(i, el){
   $(el).val(); //Get input's value
});
```

Comment: `el` is the DOM element, not a jQuery object, so you can't call `val()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

To add items to an array in JavaScript you can't use empty square brackets as you can in e.g. PHP. An alternative way is to create an empty array outside of your loop, e.g.

```
// Outside loop
var user[];
```

And then within the loop use the push() method to add items to it:

```
// Within loop
user.push(input_value);
```